# Is OnTangoImageAvailableEventHandler() multi threaded?

Tags: android, multithreading, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm currently trying to achieve environmental lighting by using the data from the camera as environment map and sampling lights from it.

What I did was

```
private int noOfSamples = 64;
private int noOfLights = 0;

public void OnTangoImageAvailableEventHandler(TangoEnums.TangoCameraId cameraId, TangoUnityImageData imageBuffer)
{
    createSamples(imageBuffer);
}
```

Then in createSamples() :

```
public void createSamples(TangoUnityImageData imageBuffer)
{
     if (m_enableEnvironmentalLighting && noOfLights < noOfSamples) 
     {
          ----- generate samples -------
          for (int i = 0; i < noOfSamples; i++)
          {
              ---- create light game object, set the position and rgb of the light.
           noOfLights++;
          }
     }
}
```

This works fine in Unity editor, and it only creates the first 64 lights, and the reflection and shading works fine. However, when it is on Tango device, no light would be created except if I remove the checking noOfLights < noOfSamples.

After removing the checking noOfLights < noOfSamples, in every frame it needs to calculate the samples again, resulting a very poor performance. Is it because the method OnTangoImageAvailableEventHandler is multi-threaded? Is there a way to only create the first 64 lights?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

create an imageBuffer var to hold the buffer. in the onTango... simply copy the buffer to that.  then create a method to interrogate that stored buffer only when you want information.

when you do grab the info, copy the buffer locally and work with it.  as the tango callbacks are on another thread and could cause segmentation faults during long operations (like your sample testing)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Out of curiosity, instead of using image buffer, would implementing ITangoVideoOverlayMultithreaded solve this problem?